# The graphic for the hat "6" is wrong/unaligned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2016

When I got the hat called "6", I recently equipped it, but one thing **really** bugged me:[image: The hat]

You can **clearly** see the left ear is unaligned with the rest of the hat. At first, I thought my eyes were tricked, but nope, it doesn't align with the eyebrows, and is father away than the other ear from the nose. Also, the eyebrow is either too long, or too much to the left. Here's a quick sketch to explain:
[image]

While of course this might be intentional (I doubt that) and it's only a minor graphical mistake, I understand it's not much of a hassle, but... it's just.. bugging me!

Comment: I guess our avatar model must have a misplaced ear.

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: Please don't.. Argh.. @Wont

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We modeled this after an image of a person and obviously were not [symmetrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_symmetry) which many people aren't, so this was, of course, by-design.

Since hats are temporary, you'll just have to live with it not being perfect. But use this bunny wearing a pancake hat as a distraction.

[image]

Comment: [Bert's face is symmetrical though!](https://i.gyazo.com/81382c238718e26d4352bca2b1048477.png)

Comment: We use the same face for all the hats and it wasn't Bert's. Maybe next year, Bert will be our model.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.

Comment: I want that bunny as a hat next year <3