# Multi-element moveable hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Whenever wearing hats, you have the option to move them to fit your face:

[image]

But wouldn't it be **super-cool** if you could change every element of the hat on it's own? *In this example, each of the eggs, and the bacon scarf.*

[Previously I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288469/346081) why some hats are asymmetrical. The answer was, a regular face isn't symmetrical either, and hats would fit to "normal" faces like this better.

It was also explained the hat makers had a person they were modelling after. Well, not all faces are the same!

By using multi-part hats where every part is moveable, it could fit to any face perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be super cool.

It wouldn't be a hat - it would be a collection of hats. Hats on your face.

... **face hats**.

I don't like face hats.

Comment: Are glasses and a scarf really a hat either? (talking about the Bacon one)

Comment: That's not a scarf, that's my eccentric pink beard